# How to sum result of loop for all file xml in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, python-requests

I'm new to programming and have a problem.
I have 4 files like this

> ```
>   <object>
>     <pose>Damage</pose>
>     <pose>Dent</pose>
>     <pose>Damage</pose>
>     <pose>Dent</pose>
>     <pose>Damage</pose>
>    </object>
> ```

I want to count amount Damage and Dent in all files.
I have done it like this but not getting the result I need.

```
            import os
            import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
            from collections import defaultdict
            
            # files are in a sub folder where this script is being ran
            path = r"D:\Non_Documents\xml"
            for filename in os.listdir(path):
                # Only get xml files
                if not filename.endswith('.xml'): continue
                # I haven't been able to get it to work by just saying 'if filename.endswith('.xml')' only if not..
                fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
                # This joins the path for each file it files so that python knows the full path / filename to trigger parser
                tree = ET.parse(fullname)
                # Parse the files..
                # print(tree)
                data = defaultdict(int)
                # Get the root of the XML tree structure
                root = tree.getroot()
                # print(fullname)
                for name in root.findall('.//name'):
                    data[name.text] += 1
                print(data)
```

This is the result i got

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, { 'Damage': 3, 'Dent': 2})
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'Dent': 29, 'Damage': 7})
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, { 'Damage': 6, 'Dent': 15})
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'Damage': 7, 'Dent': 19})
```

What do I have to do to get results like this?

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'Damage': 23, 'Dent': 65})
```

Comment: Hello, from what I see, both the declaration of your variable `data` and the `print` are in the first `for` loop. This can not work because this way, the content of `data` is calculated, printed and reseted for every file. You should see to move the declaration of `data` before the loop and the `print` after the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modify your code and exact result as you expected. You can try below code snippet.

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict

# files are in a sub folder where this script is being ran
path = r"D:\Non_Documents\xml"
data_list = []
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    # Only get xml files
    if not filename.endswith('.xml'): continue
    # I haven't been able to get it to work by just saying 'if filename.endswith('.xml')' only if not..
    fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
    # This joins the path for each file it files so that python knows the full path / filename to trigger parser
    tree = ET.parse(fullname)
    # Parse the files..
    # print(tree)
    data = defaultdict(int)
    # Get the root of the XML tree structure
    root = tree.getroot()
    # print(fullname)
    for name in root.findall('.//name'):
        data[name.text] += 1
    data_list.append(data)

result = defaultdict(int)

for data in data_list:
    for key, value in data.items():
        result[key] += value

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'Damage': 30, 'Dent': 20})
```

Answer (score 0):

Append all your Dict into a list like this below,

```
a = [defaultdict(<class 'int'>, { 'Damage': 3, 'Dent': 2}),
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'Dent': 29, 'Damage': 7}),
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, { 'Damage': 6, 'Dent': 15}),
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'Damage': 7, 'Dent': 19})]
```

use the below code to return the expected output,

```
sumDict = {'Damage': 0, 'Dent': 0}
for i in a:
    for m,n in i.items():
        sumDict.update({m:sumDict[m]+n})
```

The output will be,

```
{'Damage': 23, 'Dent': 65}
```

Thumbs up if you like mate !!!